# How do I remotely call a web service Programmatically?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm a bit new to web services and I have encountered a problem.

I need to access a remote web service through a java class, but I haven't got the foggiest idea how to do so.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: what kind of web service end point is it?  Does it use json, or xml? soap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html

Basically you construct a URL (that points to the web service), and you connect to it, read its response, etc.

The "Next >" link on this page will explain further. Follow the trail and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good libraries that abstract away all the gritty details for you. [Google Java HTTP Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) is a good one.